# how come media query won't work for mobile device?

Tags: css, media-queries

[image]

As you can see from the screen, I do have a media query CSS

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .block {
    background-color: lightblue;
    width: 100%;
    margin-top: 20px;
  }
}
```

But for mobile device with under 600px, the block won't able to display lightblue background; but resize with desktop browser works.

Why?

detail code with here: https://codepen.io/dotku/pen/VwZGKYV

Comment: Try to add: `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0">`

Answer (score 1):

The comment from @Reza works, that is add viewport meta.

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0">
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what mobile device you're testing on, but I'm assuming you're not aware of the **difference between device pixels and actual CSS pixels**: CSS pixels are an abstraction over the real pixels in your device's specs to make webpages appear consistent on all the different device sizes.

Formula:

```
CSS pixels = Physical resolution / Device Pixel Ratio
```

The `Device Pixel Ratio` itself is determined by each browser on each device independently.

On my phone, your codepen works fine and displays blue. I recommend checking out [this codepen](https://codepen.io/DavidDeprost/pen/rQjbXO), which will reveal your Device Pixel Ratio and logical resolution. Most likely your device has a CSS width larger than 600px.

Comment: Why do device pixels matter at all? This confuses the matter terribly. CSS pixels are **the only units you need to worry about** when dealing with media queries and they are standardized regardless of if you are on a 4x screen or a 1x screen.

Comment: It matters because if he is using a tablet or large phone with a CSS width larger than 600px, his media query will not trigger, regardless of the width he **thinks** his device has / the specs say it has.

Comment: The OP posted a very clear screenshot of chrome in responsive mode.

Comment: Which he also stated **does** work as he expects. It is the mobile device that doesn't work. Maybe you should reread what OP stated ..., oh and upvote my answer ;)

Answer (score 0):

On my phone, given codepen example works without *meta* tag (color change, *meta* tag is just for scaling, so this means that @media query is read properly).
Also, some new phones or phablets have *virtual* resolution 800px in portrait mode, so website should be tested on those devices.

If color doesn't change, try deleting Chrome cache on mobile phone: https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/32050?co=GENIE.Platform%3DAndroid&hl=en

I had the same problem two days ago, especially yesterday after Chrome was updated (seemed just to ignore any changes to @media queries, which showed properly on desktop in responsive mode).
After testing website with Firefox for Android (worked properly), and also with Chrome failing to reflect some changes to CSS outside @media query (background-color), it was obvious that Chrome didn't load changed CSS file from the server, but used some older locally cached version.
After deleting browsing cache, everything works as it should be (even after CSS file was changed a few times after this).